# How to show a class of structures is not axiomatizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, logic, model-theory

For example, let $F$ be a field and $L$ be the language of $F$-vector space.

(1) Prove that the class of finite dimensional $F$-vector space is not axiomatizable.

(2) Prove that if $F$ is infinite then the class of infinite dimensional $F$-vector space is not axiomatizable.

Or let $L$ be the language of rings.

(3) Prove that the class of algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ is not axiomatizable.

I think the common way to prove this type of statement would be: first suppose the class is axiomatizable. Then there is some $L$-theory axiomatizing the class. We make a new language $L'$ by adding new symbols to $L$ then construct a $L'$-theory $T'$ and show $T'$ is consistent by compactness then observe a contradiction.

However, this method requires a bit of algebra knowledge. Can anyone give some hints for the above problems I have listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** :  for all these questions, you can use the ascending Löwenheim-Skolem theorem.

Comment: Yes, I solved (1) by showing that if it is axiomatizable then it would contradict the LS theorem. However, for (2), I tried to play the same trick but I found it is totally consistent with LS theorem. For (3), no idea what to do.

Comment: Actually you can use LS for (2) as well by using this : prove that there is a infinite dimensional vector space that is elementarily equivalent to $F$. For (3), notice that an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ must be countable

Comment: For (2), since $F$ is infinite, then any vector spaces with the same cardinality bigger than $F$ are isomorphic. So if it is axiomatizable then the theory is complete. So any two models are elementarily equivalent. But F itself is not a model since it is one dimensional over itself. How I can show $F$ is equivalent to an infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: By using Löwenheim-Skolem !

Comment: I still don't get it... the LS theorem requires an infinite $L$-structure in the hypothesis. If $F$ an infinite dimensional $F$-vector space then there will be a elementary extension of $F$ of cardinality at least $|F|$ hence they are elementary equivalent. However, the thing is, $F$ is not infinite dimensional.

Comment: If $F$ is an infinite field, it is elementarily equivalent to a vector space of cardinality $> |F|$, hence of infinite dimension.

Comment: Why does $F$ being infinite implies it is equivalent to some $V$ with $|V|>|F|$? Is this a theorem from linear algebra? Could you tell me the name of this theorem? Seems like I missed something

Comment: It's Löwenheim-Skolem !

Comment: LS theorem says: If $\mathcal{M}$ is an infinite $L$-structure and $\kappa \geq max\{|M|,|L|\}$, then there is an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$ of cardinality $\kappa$. How does $LS$ implies $F$ is equivalent to a vector space of cardinality bigger than $|F|$?

Comment: Take $\mathcal{M}= F$, $\kappa$ any cardinal $>|F|$.

Comment: $\mathcal{M}$ is an infinite $L$-structure. $F$ is infinite by hypothesis but it is not an $L$-structure in this problem. Since in this problem, the $L$-structures are infinite dimensional $F$-vector spaces.

Comment: No ! $L$-structures are all vector spaces, think about it for one second (actually that's not even true : an $L$-structure is just some set with some operations)

Comment: Oh. My. God. How could I forget about the meaning of an $L$-structure. Now I get it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there; I'm glad you got it !

Comment: Form Lowenhei-Skolem, do you directly get that the vector space that's elementarily equivalent to $F$ is infinite-dimensional? Also, What is the contradiction of (2)? Is it that $Th(F)=Th(\mathcal{M})$ can't happen since one is finite dimensional and the other one is infinite dimensional? Thanks!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee : no, the point is that you can make its cardinality arbitrarily large, and in particular that can force it to be infinite dimensional, while still being elementarily equivalent to $F$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Could you explain the contradiction? What goes wrong if $F$ is elementarily equivalent to an infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: @John : well then if infinite dimensional vector spaces were axiomatizable, $F$ would be infinite dimensional, as it is elementarily equivalent to one. But it is not